# Angular - Module 'angulike' is not available! Error - don't know why?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to use angulike and have included it in my dependencies. I am also using gulp so there can't be a loading /script issue.
I keep getting the error:

[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module FullstackGeneratedApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angulike due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angulike' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

If I 'move' 'angulike' to the end, I sometimes get the same error but it says 'fsaPreBuilt' is not available instead..Its so frustrating and I don't know why this is happening!

```
window.app = angular.module('FullstackGeneratedApp', ['fsaPreBuilt', 'angulike', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.materialize', 'angular-input-stars', 'angular-stripe']);
```

Comment: check your index.html at the root of your directory to see if the script of this module is present. if not , add it manually.

Comment: Thanks!! It It works now after I added the script

Comment: Do you know if it matters where at what 'position' I inject angulike and where i add the script tag? It works but now my bootstrap and materialize stuff is screwed up so i figured its maybe because of where i added the script..

Comment: the important thing is to declare all the angular modules after the main angular script , for your case i suspect that 2 modules are using the same variables (name) , you need to check what is the error on your console and start debugging . Good lick !